# Listview Deselect C# Metro

Tags: c#, listview, microsoft-metro

How do I deselect all the values of a listview in a C# Metro application? I searched through the object browser and online and haven't been able to find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way of doing what I want. I just have a list item that says "None" which is selected by default. When I select this item, the focus shifts off the other item previously selected. The solution given by Pako would work in a traditional Desktop/WPF environment, but apparently not a Metro one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had the same problem my solution was this: list.SelectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clearing `SelectedItems` list? That's how it is normally done I think.

```
listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

Edit:
To clarify some things, here's sample WPF application that clears selected items with no problem. Maybe `Metro` applications work somewhat different but I would assume that the logic should be the same.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="listView">
        <ListViewItem>Item 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 4</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <Button Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Clear selection" />
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the code beind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
    }
```

On button click list items are correctly deselected and no exception is being thrown.

Comment: Hmm I tried this and when the app gets to this line it causes the program to crash.

Comment: Specifically I says:
"An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: Also what you suggested would remove the items in the listview and not simply deselect them.

Comment: I've added sample code I used to test my solution and everything works (but note it was normal `WPF` application, but I assume that in `Metro` everything works similarly). Please post some sample code in your question and all exception details so we will be able to help you.

Comment: You're right about it working properly in WPF, but in metro it seems like clearing all selected items removes the items from the listview. Thanks for your help though, but I found another way of doing what I want. I just have a list item that says "None" which is selected by default. Basically I'm making a list of options and want the user to select one. Thanks again.